# FAST Search verify noindex

Tags: noindex, fastsearch

In FAST Search, content can be ignored a couple of ways -

- By using a meta tag
- By encompassing links into a  tags

Is there a way to verify that this is actually working other than doing a before and after on the search results?

Answer (score 0):

No. Test on a small content source if you are in doubt. If you are on 2010 or earlier you can use docpush and doclog to test and log the result of a single document.